# Can't create username for PostgreSQL

Tags: server, permissions, ruby, postgresql

After installing rails and trying to install PostgreSQL in the terminal (following these instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04),

I run into this when I try to set up a username using "sudo -u postgres createuser -s username":

'could not change directory to "/home/UbuntuUsername": Permission denied
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "UbuntuUsername" already exists'

How do I get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm completely new to Ubuntu (im running 14.04), so forgive me if this is simple to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already created a Postgres role called UbuntuUsername. Trying to do that the second time will result in an error as the role already exists. I think you can proceed with the instructions.

(the first error - "could not change directory..." is probably unimportant and harmless and is caused by `sudo -u postgres ...` executed in your home directory)

Comment: Thank you so much! I continued and everything seems to be working fine